# Counter words of a list in python

Tags: python, list, loops, filter, counter

I have a counter of frequences of texts variabile name is `frequenzaparolespamglob[]`. I have a list from the raw input `parole[]` and I need to print the `frequenzaparolespamglob[parole]`. I know how to print only one word:

```
print (frequenzaparolespamglob['free']) # for example
```

But if I want to print only the instances of parole in the counter `frequenzaparolespamglob`. How can I do? Should I do a loop?

```
frequenzaparolehamglob=Counter()
i=0
while i < len(frequenzaparoleham):
    frequenzaparolehamglob= frequenzaparolehamglob + frequenzaparoleham[i]
    i=i+1

frequenzaparolespamglob=Counter()
i=0
while i < len(frequenzaparolespam):
    frequenzaparolespamglob= frequenzaparolespamglob + frequenzaparolespam[i]
    i=i+1

sommafreqspam= sum(frequenzaparolespamglob.values())

sommafreqham= sum(frequenzaparolehamglob.values())

frequenzaparolespamglob=sorted(frequenzaparolespamglob.items())
frequenzaparolehamglob=sorted(frequenzaparolehamglob.items())

inputemail = input('Inserisci una email:')
parole = nltk.word_tokenize(inputemail)
parole=[i for i in parole if i not in listastop]
parole = rimuovipunteggiatura.tokenize (str(parole))
parole=[i for i in parole if i.isalpha()]
parole=[ps.stem(parola) for parola in parole]
frequenzaparolespam=list(frequenzaparolespamglob)
risultato=Counter(frequenzaparolespamglob)
print(risultato[parole])
```

Comment: Don't worry, your English is not bad at all.

Comment: Please clarify what you want to achive? What is the desired output?

Comment: So `{i: frequenzaparolespamglob[i] for i in parole}`, i.e. the `Counter` filtered using only the keys from `parole`?

Comment: I want the list of frequence of each member of parole[] taken from frequenzaparolespamglob

Comment: Thanks dhke.. I need a filtered using only the keys in the list parole[] {i: frequenzaparolespamglob[i] for i in parole} but

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: Thanks Ivan but... frequenzaparolespamglob - parole

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'

Comment: frequenzaparolespam and frequenzaparoleham is count of words in a single email.. but i need  frequenzeparolehamglob, because i have to apply for bayes theorem..

Comment: difference = [item for item in frequenzaparolespamglob if item not in parole] print me all frequenzaparolespamglob and not only the parole[i], that would be only 4 values if the sentence is 4 words..

Answer (score 0):

The solution was:

```html
filt_spam = {k:v for (k,v) in frequenzaparolespamglob.items() if k in parole}
filt_ham = {k:v for (k,v) in frequenzaparolehamglob.items() if k in parole}
```

Now i have an other question.. In python 2.7 people can print only the number of frequency.. filter_ham.values() .. Now i can't.. Can anyone say how can i print only the number as a list?